# Почему не парсится сайт?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Есть [сайт](https://shop.casio.ru/catalog/g-shock-youth/ga-700ske-7aer/) с которого мне нужно забрать хотя бы название фирмы часов и их модель. Я использую `selenium`, вот код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

# options.add_argument("--headless")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )
headers = {
    'authority': 'shop.casio.ru',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36'
}
url = "https://shop.casio.ru/catalog/g-shock-youth/ga-700ske-7aer/"
def get_data(url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        name = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT , "Наручные часы").text
        print(name)
        time.sleep(3)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

def main():
    get_data(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

При парсинге не находит мой элемент. Я уже смотрел `html` страницу которую он мне отдаёт и там только `js` скрипты и другое, но не информация. Хотя если зайти в запросы то там будет `document` со всей вёрсткой и `ajax.php`.
Я не знаю что такое `ajax`, может быть это связано как-то. Возможно ли этот сайт спарсить или там стоит какая-то защита?

Comment: Сделаю на примере с названием часов. Я бы попробовал использовать `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME , "product-card__title").text`
Вот только не помню, что возвращает этот метод, возможно вам придется написать это как `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME , "product-card__title")[0].text`
[Про аттрибуты find_element можно почитать тут](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by)

Comment: Парсинг сайта casio может поможет
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kK4j6o3bw4E&list=PLqGS6O1-DZLprgEaEeKn9BWKZBvzVi_la&index=9&ab_channel=PythonToday

Comment: Давно не балуюсь селениумом, посему не буду оформлять ответ, но погуглите в сторону ожидания появления элемента. Дождитесь прогрузки этого элемента и только потом продолжайте парсинг

Comment: не знаю как это заработало, я вроде уже пытался использовать driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME , "product-card__title").text , но оно чудом сработало.